# How do I configure MSMTP such that it will work with Request tracker?

Tags: smtp, sendmail, request-tracker, email

I have installed Request tracker v4.0.8 in CentOS 6.2 system using [this documentation](http :// harbot. me/2012/05/22/how-to-install-request-tracker-4-0-5-in-centos6/).

I'm using msmtp for outgoing email. msmtp works in command line and I get email. But when a ticket is created in RT, it doesn't send mail.

Here is the /var/log/messages:

```
Tmailer: CALL /usr/local/bin/msmtp -nt -oi -t RETURNED 74
Dec 24 16:21:39 RT RT: <rt-4.0.8-8887-1356346299-1411.17-3-0@organization> sent  To: user@organization (/usr/local/rt/sbin/../lib/RT/Action/SendEmail.pm:316)
Dec 24 16:21:39 RT RT: <rt-4.0.8-8887-1356346299-748.17-4-0@organization> #17/280 - Scrip 4 On Create Notify AdminCcs (/usr/local/rt/sbin/../lib/RT/Action/SendEmail.pm:285)
Dec 24 16:21:39 RT RT: <rt-4.0.8-8887-1356346299-748.17-4-0@organization> No recipients found. Not sending. (/usr/local/rt/sbin/../lib/RT/Interface/Email.pm:382)
Dec 24 16:21:39 RT RT: Ticket 17 created in queue 'General' by root (/usr/local/rt/sbin/../lib/RT/Ticket.pm:688)
```

What is the error returned 74?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help debug, what is your $MailCommand set to in RT_SiteConfig.pm?

Also, make sure you are testing with a ticket that will send email. The brief log you provided indicated that no mail would be sent (No recipients found. Not sending). If you have the default setting for NotifyActor (which is off) you won't see email for things you do. You can turn this off in the RT_SiteConfig.pm file or individually via the web UI on the options page to see email for all of your actions.

Comment: $MailCommand is the msmtp binary path. But then I switched to sendmail. Thank you for the reply.